# Flutter Hive storing box on network drive

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, flutter-hive

I'm working on a project that requires multiple clients to simultaneously work on synchronised data. There will be 4 clients working together connected to the same network. I've been looking at various database solutions for this. Now I'm not looking to go super deep into anything ridiculously advanced so I have mostly considered Hive for a nice lightweight local database, or firebase for a good cloud option. A key thing to consider in this project is it will be deployed in an area with quite spotty internet, so ideally I want everything running over the local network.

Both do come with drawbacks. Firebase requires a steady network connection. Lose that and the whole system is useless.

I'd like to use hive but I need to find a way to make the data sync between the 4 computers in the system. Is it possible to put my hive directory on a network drive and have all 4 computers access the boxes there?

Alternatively, are there any other options anyone can recommend? Can Firebase be run over LAN? I know they have a local emulator suite, but is that suitable for a production app?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1):

Your question isn't specific enough to answer directly.

Firebase Firestore provides a non-SQL database running on a Google Cloud server. Hive is only a SQL-like database. According to Hive's documentation, Hive can sync data with a server. Although to my knowledge this isn't really common.

You're asking for a way to sync data from multiple clients. As you've mentioned, the easiest solution would be to use Firebase Firestore.
Since these clients are on the same network, you can set up a local server. It might also be possible for the app itself to create a local server (like a LAN). But keep in mind, every other solution will be more error-prone and difficult to set up than Firestore.

Comment: If a question is not clear, use the comment function to ask for further details.

Comment: Sorry I kept it broad to try get suggestions for many solutions. Essentially I want to set up a database that can ideally keep multiple clients in sync over a local network. Worst case I'm ok with going something online however after doing some firebase experimentation have discovered that there's no windows support for firebase which throws a spanner in the works.